docs as baseUrl for docusaurus fails on build
I can't seem to give /docs/ as the baseUrl.
baseUrl: '/docs/',

Any name other than docs works.
So its docs restricted somewhere in the code ? Because build fails when giving docs.
Using docusaurus 3.5

Why are you setting your baseUrl to the /docs folder?
The baseUrl should be dependent on where you are deploying your Docusaurus site (GitHub, GitLab, Netlify, etc.) and the project's path on that platform.
For example, if deploying on GitHub, and your GitHub project repository url is:
username.github.io/myproject

Then baseUrl in this example is: /myproject/

"Base URL for your site. Can be considered as the path after the host."
Reference: https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/docusaurus-config#baseUrl

I wanted to host it at myDomain.com/docs
